# How to make my mesh/geometry/polygon back to normal

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, sculpting, 3d-printing

[image]

It is looks like distorted mesh/geometry/polygon in first arrow.
How to fix it? back to normal like second arrow

Comment: you can use the Remesh tool (button on the top right of he 3D view, or shortcuts Shift R to set the size and Ctrl R to apply), but it will change the topology of your whole object, you can also select a Draw brush, put the Strength value at 0, choose the size of the tris in the Dyntopo panel, but it will create tris, not quads

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.